# shortcut for enable/disable windows 10 firewall rules?

Tags: windows-10, windows-firewall

*how do I enable/disable Windows Firewall rules using a shortcut?*

I tryed all and this

"run, netsh.exe advfirewall firewall set rule name="RuleName" new enable=no"

is not working as a shortcut command

Comment: Can you put the command into a batch file? You need to slightly modify it though.

Comment: how do i modify it?